# what is a recommended way to create a dependency for a windows forms application?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, dependencies

I want to associate a text or xml file with my project. So when the applications gets published this text file should tag along. How do you do this in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd just add the file to the project, set the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output directory` to `Always Copy`. I don't normally publish projects though (I just copy the files) but I'd assume this would still be the correct way.